# Using facebook Graph API to fetch instagram video metrics using short code

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, microservices, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I would like to use Facebook's Graph API to fetch Instagram Media in my application. users will submit a media URL {https://www.instagram.com/p/CP2rpLyCwPn/}. How can I get media ID {videoId} from the shortcode CP2rpLyCwPn to retrieve media further using videoId (caption,media_product_type,media_type,media_url,thumbnail_url,video_title,comments_count, etc.)?

Is there any way other than embedding the URL to fetch IG media_id http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/CP2rpLyCwPn?

I'd be grateful if someone could help me find any other solution.

Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to do that for just any arbitrary media object. Will your app user be the _owner_ of the IG media?

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript, you can simply do this

```
let url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/CP2rpLyCwPn/";

console.log(url.split("p/")[1]);
```

You need to be sure that the URL will always be the same.

Comment: my question is how to get video_id from the provided shortcode.

Comment: So that is what the above code does. run in browser console to see the result.

Comment: my question was related to facebook graph API to pull video details. And the code we see in the URL is not a video ID it is a shortcode instead. I need to find the video ID using the shortcode.

Comment: can you share the link to the documentation page?